# How to fix: Semantical Error Annotation ORM\Column is not allowed to be declared on method

Tags: symfony, annotations

When I try to create or edit a Game, I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] Annotation @ORM\Column is not allowed to be
>   declared on method AppBundle\Entity\Game::setType(). You may only use
>   this annotation on these code elements: PROPERTY, ANNOTATION.

What's causing this and what can I do to fix this?

**Game**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Game
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="game")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GameRepository")
 */
class Game
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PlayLog", mappedBy="game")
     */
    private $playlogs;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->playlogs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="games")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min = "3",
     *  max = "100"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Game
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column (options={"default" = none})
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlaylogs()
    {
        return $this->playlogs;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $playlogs
     */
    public function setPlaylogs($playlogs)
    {
        $this->playlogs = $playlogs;
    }

    public function addPlayLog(PlayLog $playlog)
    {
        $this->playlog->add($playlog);
        $playlog->setPlayLogs($this);
    }

}
```

**GameController**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Game;
use AppBundle\Entity\PlayLog;
use AppBundle\Entity\Type;
use AppBundle\Form\GameType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
/**
 * Game controller.
 *
 * @Route("game")
 */
class GameController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all game entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="game_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dql = "SELECT game FROM AppBundle:Game game JOIN game.type type ORDER BY game.name";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
        /*
         * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
         */
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $result = $paginator->paginate(
             $query,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            $request->query->getInt('limit', 25)
        );
//        dump(get_class($paginator));

        return $this->render('game/index.html.twig', array(
            'games' => $result,
            'max_limit_error' => 25
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="game_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {

        $game = new Game();

        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\GameType', $game);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($game);
            $em->flush($game);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('game_show', array('id' => $game->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('game/new.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="game_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Game $game)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($game);


        return $this->render('game/show.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="game_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Game $game)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($game);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\GameType', $game);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('game_show', array('id' => $game->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('game/edit.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),

        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/log", name="game_log")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function addLogAction(Request $request, Game $game)
    {
        $playlog = new PlayLog();
        $form = $this->createForm(GameType::class, $game);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //Save playLog
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($playlog);
            $em->flush();

        }
        // Render / return view incl. formulier.
        return $this->render('game/log.html.twig', array(
            'game' => $game,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a game entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="game_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Game $game)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($game);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($game);
            $em->flush($game);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('game_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a game entity.
     *
     * @param Game $game The game entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Game $game)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('game_delete', array('id' => $game->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

**Type**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TypeRepository")
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Game", mappedBy="type")
     */
    private $games;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->games = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGames()
    {
        return $this->games;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $games
     */
    public function setGames($games)
    {
        $this->games = $games;
    }

    public function addGame(Game $game)
    {
        $this->games->add($game);
        $game->setType($this);
    }
    public function removeGame(Game $game)
    {
        $this->games->removeElement($game);
    }



}
```

**TypeType**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Type'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_type';
    }


}
```

**game/new.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% import "macros.html.twig" as macro %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Game</h1>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Type
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.type) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            {{ macro.btnSubmitAndCancel() }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you cannot use the `@ORM\Column()` annotation on a method. You have to remove it from your Game entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column (options={"default" = none}) <--- REMOVE ME PLEASE
 * @param mixed $type
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
}
```